# Use wget o curl for multiple download

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, wget

I would like to download all the audio files on this [VoxForge web page](http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/it/Trunk/Audio/Main/16kHz_16bit/). Unfortunately I don't understand how to download them all in a folder of my choice with a single command from the terminal using wget or alternatively curl. I tried wget like this without success:

```
wget http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/it/Trunk/Audio/Main/16kHz_16bit/ -P / home / user / download /
```

doing this way I get only an html index file

Answer (score 1):

```
curl http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/it/Trunk/Audio/Main/16kHz_16bit/ | awk -F \" '/tgz/ { print "http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/it/Trunk/Audio/Main/16kHz_16bit/"$6 }' | xargs wget '{}' \;
```

Curl the link and parse the output with awk to get the full download address of each tgz file. Pipe this through to xargs and wget to download the links

Answer (score 1):

The following command should work for you.

```
wget --directory-prefix=download_folder --no-directories --mirror --no-parent http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/it/Trunk/Audio/Main/16kHz_16bit
```